# Updating from Laravel 8 to 9 problem with Diglactic\Breadcrumbs package

Tags: laravel

I updated my composer.json file and ran composer update. Everything was updated, and the composer update finished with the following error:

> ```
> BadMethodCallException
>   Method Diglactic\Breadcrumbs\Manager::register does not exist.
>   at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php:113
>     109▕      */
>     110▕     public function __call($method, $parameters)
>     111▕     {
>     112▕         if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
>   ➜ 113▕             throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
>     114▕                 'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method
>     115▕             ));
>     116▕         }
>     117▕
> ```
>
> i   Bad Method Call: Did you mean
> Diglactic\Breadcrumbs\Manager::exists() ?

My front-end code now throws an error: Method Diglactic\Breadcrumbs\Manager::register does not exist.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message indicates that the register method does not exist in the Diglactic\Breadcrumbs\Manager class. This could be due to changes in the Diglactic\Breadcrumbs package when you updated your Laravel application from version 8 to 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breadcrumbs::for replaces the old Breadcrumbs::register in the Routes\Breadcrumbs.php file.